How does the LM358 works in this IR proximity sensor?
I’m having trouble understanding how the LM358 works as a voltage comparator. From what I know, the logic is that if the voltage on the non-inverting input (V+) is higher than the voltage on the inverting input (V-), the output should be HIGH. In other words, if V+ > V-, the output will be HIGH, and if the opposite is true, the output will be LOW.
What’s confusing me is how this logic translates when programming the sensor. In the code, I’m using the condition if (!(PINB & (1<<PB2))), which means that when the sensor is detecting (or when the photodiode detects the IR light, and the voltage is high), the pin PB2 (where the sensor is connected) should be LOW. My project works well with this logic.

I’m not sure how this ties together with the voltage comparator logic. Could you explain this to me?

There are different modules that may work differently. Which exact module you have, i.e. post a photo or link to one that looks exactly like the one you have? Basically your module might not look like as per the schematics.

Please measure the voltage at the output of the module for both cases, with and without detection.

Are you aware that the voltage cannot be higher than the forward voltage of the LED? Does your test sketch read a HIGH at all? (Please [edit] your question to clarify.)

Here is a typical AliExpress hobbyist proximity detector module.

I don't see that anyone has published a schematic so I'll produce one below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You will note a number of differences between the (even more hobbyist-grade) schematic in the question and the commercial module.

An LM393 comparator is used rather than an LM358 op-amp

When there is light detected the non-inverting input is lower than the inverting, so the output is logic '0' and the OUT LED is illuminated. If the light is interrupted the output will go to '1' and the OUT LED will turn off.

There's a proper power supply bypass capacitor and another capacitor to slow the response to rapid light changes.

The 10kΩ pullup on the output ensures a proper logic level '1' when the output is high (open collector). On a 3.3V supply that's certainly not guaranteed with an LM358 (and pulling the output up through an LED will not guarantee it with an LM393).


